# Launch program with startup arguments Sandboxie

Tags: batch-file, arguments, startup, sandbox

**What I'm trying to accomplish**

I'm trying to launch Spotify using Sandboxie (https://www.sandboxie.com) with custom startup parameters with batch.

**What I tried**

I've tried this batch-script which launches it without any argument:

```
"C:\Program Files\Sandboxie\Start.exe" /box:SandBox1 "MyApplication.exe";
```

The argument I want to launch the program with is `--no-sandbox` so I tried adding the launch argument after the quotation marks:

```
"C:\Program Files\Sandboxie\Start.exe" /box:SandBox1 "MyApplication.exe" --no-sandbox;
```

I've also read this (https://www.codenong.com/cs106939919) guide (not official) on how to launch programs with Sandboxie using batch (command line) but I've not found any custom startup argument function on that guide.

**Issues**

Adding the argument after the quotation marks did not launch the program with that argument. I also tried adding the argument **inside** the quotation marks but I got thrown an error that that file did not exist.

**Question**

How can I launch a application with Sandboxie using batch and passing an startup argument?

Comment: Why are you not providing a full path to `"MyApplication.exe"`?, Is there a specific reason why you're deliberately not providing us with the actual process name? or what type of process it is? What is the trailing semi-colon for?

Comment: - I can share the full path: `"C:\Users\User1\AppData\Roaming\Spotify\Spotify.exe"`
- About the semicolon: I thought batch are using those to mark the end of a line

Comment: Please remove the semicolon, it isn't required, nor is it a valid ending character for command lines in batch files. What happens if you make that change yourself? `"C:\Program Files\Sandboxie\Start.exe" /box:SandBox1 "C:\Users\User1\AppData\Roaming\Spotify\Spotify.exe"`, with and without the `-insecure` and/or `--no-sandbox` options. BTW, as [you've already posted this as an issue on the official GitHub page](https://github.com/sandboxie/sandboxie/issues/71), you should really have mentioned it in your question itself.

Comment: Wow that actually worked, thank you!